# Understanding "NOT EXISTS" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a hard time understanding a SQL statement (SQL Server dialect) like below:

```
select 
  id, 
  book, 
  '11W', -- acnt type
  '000', -- prod code
  '0'   -- acnt category
from XYZ_TABLE x
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from XYZ_TABLE where [acnt type] = '11w' and [prod code] = '000' and [acnt category] = '0' and id = x.id and book = x.book)
```

I looked into this forum for the semantics of `NOT EXISTS` and `Select 1 ...` and kind of having an idea, but I'm here still struggling in understanding what the above tried to achieve, most puzzling is that only one table is involved in all the comparisons.

BTW, I don't have permission to run the SQL statement so all are guess works.

Comment: You can run your SQL statements on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Its hard to know how to answer your question, `NOT EXISTS` means precisely that, the record in the sub-query doesn't not exist. And the record in the sub-query will be matching (or not matching) columns in the main query - in this case `x.`. Your example itself doesn't make sense, which is probably why you are confused. But a quick google will find your hundreds of examples.

Comment: If you don't understand what that query is written to achieve, then **ASK** the person that wrote it. And then ask that person about the bad habit of not defining an alias for every table and not using it for every column reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query (I've added qualified column names to all columns):

```
select x.id, x.book, '11W' as acnt_type '000' as prod_code, '0' acnt_category
from XYZ_TABLE x
where not exists (select 1
                  from XYZ_TABLE x2
                  where x2.id = x.id and x2.book = x.book and
                        x2.[acnt type] = '11w' and
                        x2.[prod code] = '000' and
                        x2.[acnt category] = '0'
                 );
```

The subquery is a *correlated subquery*.  I'll get into that in a moment.  `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` return "true" if the subquery returns *any* rows.  These operators do not care about the contents of the rows and `1` is easy to type.

What is this doing?  The following is a *conceptual* description.  It is going through all rows in `XYZ_TABLE`.

For each row, the subquery is looking for a matching row that has the following characteristics:

- Same `id` and `book` value as the row in the outer query.  This is the correlation clause which I moved to the first comparison in the `WHERE`.
- The account, product, and category specified in the `WHERE`.

When there is *no* match, the row in the outer query is "accepted" for the result set, so it is output.  That is, `id`/`book` pairs without the matching three columns are in the result set.

Does this do anything useful?  Yes.  Such a query is typically part of an `insert` statement to insert missing rows -- where missing are id/book combinations with the other three columns.

Is this correct?  Probably not.  The `XYZ_TABLE` can clearly have duplicates of `id`/`book` based on the logic here.  The result set might have duplicates as well.  That is usually undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#g-using-not-exists) provides quite easy to understand explanation:

> NOT EXISTS works as the opposite as EXISTS. The WHERE clause in NOT
> EXISTS is satisfied if no rows are returned by the subquery. The
> following example finds rows in the DimCustomer table where the
> LastName and BirthDate do not match any entries in the
> ProspectiveBuyers table. SQL

```
SELECT a.LastName, a.BirthDate  
FROM DimCustomer AS a  
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
(SELECT *   
    FROM dbo.ProspectiveBuyer AS b  
    WHERE (a.LastName = b.LastName) AND (a.BirthDate = b.BirthDate)) ;
```

Comment: thanks. But your SQL involves two different tables: DimCustomer and ProspectiveBuyer, the logic is easy to understand when two tables involved. My original SQL involves only one table, which makes the logic a little convoluted.